# Putting ComboBox in a one special row in ListView in WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, listview, mvvm, combobox

How to put a Combobox to a special row of a listview (WPF, VB.net)?

There is a ListView that has two columns. The columns are "Parameter" and "Values". The second column has different types (such as numbers, strings and "Selectable values") and is editable. The "Selectable values" have to appear in a Combobox.
One of the ways that I think about, is conditional XAML tags (I don`t know if it is possible or not ?) .

I tried this code but it shows Combobox for all rows in listview :

```
 <ListView x:Name="listView"
      HorizontalAlignment="Left"
      Height="237"
      Margin="40,34,0,0"
      VerticalAlignment="Top"
      Width="447"
      ItemsSource="{Binding Values}">
  <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
      <GridViewColumn Header="Parameter"
                  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=LName}"
                  Width="100" />
      <GridViewColumn Header="Value"
                  Width="150">
        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}, Path=ItemsSource}"
                  Width="120">
                    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                   <DataTemplate>
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Type}" />
                </DataTemplate>
              </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ComboBox>
          </DataTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
      </GridViewColumn>
    </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

I only want to use Combobox for one row while the type of the rest of rows are double or string. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you share more information on structure of the "Values" that are bound to the ItemsSource of listview?